# Meaning of "as ... as any ... someone had ever done"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Recently I have been reading "The Lost Symbol" and there is a sentence I find hard to understand.

> The wooden stair descending to the Capitol's subbasement were as steep and shallow as any stairs Langdon had ever traversed.

From the context, it sounds Langdon has never traversed a stair as steep as this one, but the sentence itself seems to be saying that Langdon always traverses stairs as steep as these.

What does the author mean here?

Comment: Are you sure you've transcribed it correctly? I suspect "stairs"rather than "stair", and I am confused by "steep and shallow", which to me are antonyms.

Comment: Yes,I checked,it's stairs.

Comment: @Colin Fine: *Shallow* in this context refers to the narrowness of each step (the horizontal surface), relative to the height of each riser (the vertical surface). The risers are higher than the step width, so the stair is steep. A flight of stairs can be *a stair* or *the stairs* - although not usually *a stairs*, for reasons that escape me. It's a bit odd to mix singular and plural, but the writer was can reasonably use singular for the first one, and I think it would be at least as odd to use singular in the second reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I guess that must be the meaning of "shallow", but only because "steep" is there, which rules out _all_ the obvious meanings for "shallow". I find it a very strange use. Is it a US thing? Would you understand "a shallow staircase" in that sense?

Comment: @Colin Fine: I most certainly **wouldn't** understand "shallow staircase" in isolation to mean "steep"! Witness [shallow slope](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shallow+slope&year_start=1963&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and [shallow gradient](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shallow+gradient&year_start=1963&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which would *always* mean the complete opposite! But I think of it as *"How far into the step does your foot go?"* - if it's shallow, you won't be able to use your heels for support when climbing up the stairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first interpretation is almost right. It means he'd never traversed stairs **steeper** than these. (It's odd, however, to speak of 'traversing' stairs.)

Comment: So "as … as any … someone had ever done” is some kind of pattern to mean something is beyond someone's experience?

Comment: @Barrie That's because it's Dan Brown.

Comment: @vince, no. More like AT the limit of someones experience

Comment: @vince: As Kevin says.

Comment: Thanks guys! one more question, if I say something is beyond someones experience,is there any similar expression can do that?

Comment: @vince: It might be better to post that as a separate question.