# How to use " as .... as " to mean something is beyond someones experience

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I found the following  means something AT the limit of someones experience

> ["The wooden stair descending to the Capitol's subbasement were as steep and shallow as any stairs Langdon had ever traversed."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64930/meaning-of-as-as-any-someone-had-ever-done)

So I was wonder how to use similar expression to say something is beyond someones experience.

Comment: I'd say, avoid it and use more...than. The basic meaning of as...as is "exactly the same as", so this usage to indicate an extreme makes it feel ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the expression *as .. as* to mean *beyond someone's experience* then you have to qualify it in someway. For example:

- The wooden stairs descending to the Capitol's subbasement were **twice** as steep and shallow as any stairs Langdon had ever traversed.

Alternatively, you can use the comparatives of the adjectives and the word **than**:

- The wooden stairs descending to the Capitol's subbasement were *steeper* and *shallower* **than** any stairs Langdon had ever traversed.

Answer (score 0):

Given a phrase *X was as Y as Z had ever...*, indicating that X is at an extreme of Z's experience, convert the first *as* to *more*, and the second to *than*, to indicate that X is beyond Z's experience.  Your example becomes:

> The wooden stairs descending to the Capitol's subbasement were more steep and shallow than any stairs Langdon had ever traversed.

[I changed *stair* to *stairs* for agreement with verb *were*. An alternative is *the wooden stair ... was ...*]

Comment: Would it still be right if the word **more** is omitted,strictly?

Comment: I don't know if you mean "replace first *as* with nothing" or "leave first *as* in place"; but either would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If OP wants to keep the *as ... as any* construction, he you could say...

> [...[it's] as whim-driven as any big-label new-wave pop could possibly be — **and then some**.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8dHstWRgcM4C&pg=PA70&dq=%22as%20any%22%20%22and%20then%20some%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NZSRT6eHDqjQ0QXmztjjAQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBDhu#v=onepage&q=%22as%20any%22%20%22and%20then%20some%22&f=false)
>
> [...physically they are as fine a body of men as any — **and then some**.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3BAMAAAAYAAJ&q=%22as%20any%22%20%22and%20then%20some%22&dq=%22as%20any%22%20%22and%20then%20some%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aZaRT7nRFcKo0AWH4vn2AQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBDiiAg)

...where *and then some* is a (primarily spoken) final clause to a statement, meaning *whatever was just mentioned, only more so*.